# Get URL of image from Picture Library using CAML

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, caml, sharepoint-list

How is it possible to get the URL of an image that is stored in a Picture Library using CAML?

Currently, I've made a CAML Query and run it in the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx), and am seeing values like `ows_LinkFilename`, `ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu`, and `ows_LinkFilename2` -- fields that store the URL of the image. (They contain what I need - image.jpg or image2.gif, etc.) When I implement it and output the value in that field, I get an "Undefined."

Is it even possible to access the URL from just the file itself? Do I need to make one of the required fields in the Picture Library the name of the image? (image.jpg)

Below is a snippet of the jQuery.

```
var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ows_LinkFilename' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                            "</ViewFields>";

        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<IsNotNull>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                            "</IsNotNull>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='Display_x0020_Order' Ascending='True' />" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

         $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,
                webURL: rootURL,
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                            var name = ($(this).attr("ows_LinkFilename"));

                console.log(name);
```

Thank you so much for your help.

AA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `"<FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl' />"`, and then having `var url = ($(this).attr("ows_EncodedAbsUrl"));` instead of `var name = ($(this).attr("ows_LinkFilename"));`, it pulls the whole URL of the image.